Rich text editor image deletion not working properly
`I have created a custom rich text editor using react-draft-wysiwyg and draft-js. in there I have implemented the image adding functionality too. but when I delete an image by pressing the backspace button it shows the image has been removed from the editor. but when I submitting the data  , I can see the image is not removed. Another case is sometimes Image can be deleted with one backspace press .sometimes I have to press the backspace for three times. In that case where I have to press the backspace for three times the image is actually get deleted. only for the scenarios I have to press it for one time where the issue exists.

import React from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
import './styles.scss';

const CustomRichTextField = React.forwardRef(
  ({
    onChange, value, label, placeholder, defaultValue = '', options, toolbarCustomButtons,
  }: any) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty());

    React.useEffect(() => {
      const contentBlock = htmlToDraft((value.startsWith('<img>') ? `<p>${value}</p>` : value) || '');
      const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
      setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      const contentBlock = htmlToDraft((value.startsWith('<img>') ? `<p>${defaultValue}</p>` : defaultValue) || '');
      const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
      setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
    }, [defaultValue]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
      }
    }, [editorState]);

return (
  <Box>
    <Typography variant="body1">{label}</Typography>
    <Editor
      stripPastedStyles
      placeholder={placeholder}
      editorState={editorState}
      toolbar={options === undefined ? {
        options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'emoji', 'history', 'remove'],
      } :options}
      toolbarClassName="richTextToolbar"
      wrapperClassName="richTextWrapper"
      editorClassName="richTextEditor"
      onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
      toolbarCustomButtons={toolbarCustomButtons}
    />

  </Box>
);
},
);`

export default CustomRichTextField;`

below is my updated code which i tried to solve the isseu by updating the logics.
const CustomRichTextField = React.forwardRef(
  ({ onChange, value, label, placeholder, defaultValue = '', options, toolbarCustomButtons }, ref) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => {
      const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(defaultValue || '');
      const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
      return EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
    });

    // Effect to update editor state when the value prop changes
    useEffect(() => {
      if (value !== draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))) {
        const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(value);
        const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
        setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
      }
    }, [value]);

    // Effect to notify parent component when editor state changes
    useEffect(() => {
      if (onChange) {
        onChange(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
      }
    }, [editorState, onChange]);

    // Handler for editor state changes
    const handleEditorStateChange = useCallback((state) => {
      setEditorState(state);
    }, []);

    return (
      <Box>
        <Typography variant="body1">{label}</Typography>
        <Editor
          stripPastedStyles
          placeholder={placeholder}
          editorState={editorState}
          toolbar={options || {
            options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'emoji', 'history', 'remove'],
          }}
          toolbarClassName="richTextToolbar"
          wrapperClassName="richTextWrapper"
          editorClassName="richTextEditor"
          onEditorStateChange={handleEditorStateChange}
          toolbarCustomButtons={toolbarCustomButtons}
        />
      </Box>
    );
  },
);

export default CustomRichTextField;

